# How would I make each one of these faces a separate "plank?"

Tags: modeling

Just curious how I would make each of these faces a separate, movable, solid, rectangle. Attempting to make a wooden shack. Thanks everyone :)[image]

Comment: if you want to separate tow faces you can select the edge between them and press V

Comment: The general tool to split. 'Rip' edges is V on the keyboard. You can split multiple edges at once, but if there's one that can't be ripped included in the selection, it won't play. So don't  include any edges that are not shared by more than one face.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non destructive technique I like to use that works for simple cases, when you don't want to break the model apart or need to separate into different objects.

1. Add an *Edge Split* modifier to your base mesh
2. *Solidify* it a desired distance
3. Now add a *Bevel* modifier and limit it to *Angle*
4. Enter *Edit Mode*, select and the desired edges
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and *Mark Sharp*
6. Adjust *Bevel* distance as desired, if necessary disable *Clamp*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select your wall, hit <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd> (Edge Split), then hit <kbd>P</kbd> separate by loose parts.

The gif cut off the options but thats all I did.

[image]